# Click event not firing for dynamic link button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am creating a Job Listing page in my application. I have a requirement like the job seeker clicks on **FIND JOBS**  Button, the jobs are listed. I am creating **dynamic tables** for displaying the jobs. I have a **dynamic link button** for each table for the job seeker for **APPLY FOR THE JOB** of his choice.

**The aspx page**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function RedirectTo(id) {
            window.location.href = 'ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx?id=' + id;
            return false;
        }
</script>

   <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilter" runat="server" CssClass="searchMainbtn" ForeColor="White" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFilter_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                         </asp:DropDownList>                    

                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Button ID="btnFindJobs" runat="server" Text="Find Jobs" CssClass="searchMainbtn" Width="103px" OnClick="btnFindJobs_Click" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:Label runat="server" Width="388px" ></asp:Label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" ForeColor="Crimson" Width="205px"></asp:Label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbLogOut" Text="Log Out" OnClick="lbLogOut_Click" ForeColor="White" Font-Underline="false" CssClass="searchMainbtn"  Width="103px" Height="20px"></asp:LinkButton>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>

<div> <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></div>
```

**The aspx.cs page**

```
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    fillDropDownList();

                    lblError.Visible = false;
                    hlError.Visible = false;        
                }

                if (Page.IsPostBack)
                {

                    lblError.Visible = false;
                    hlError.Visible = false;        
                    industryName = ddlFilter.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
                    lblJobName.Text = industryName.ToUpper() + " JOBS";
                    this.Rows = getTableRows();
                    this.Columns = Int32.Parse("1");       
                }
public void fillDropDownList()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [OfinityJobSearch].[dbo].[tm_TargetedIndustry]", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    ddlFilter.DataSource = dt;
    ddlFilter.DataTextField = "s_IndustryName";
    ddlFilter.DataValueField = "s_ID";
    ddlFilter.DataBind();
    ddlFilter.Items.Insert(0, "Filter Jobs");
    da.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}

protected void btnFindJobs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Rows = getTableRows();
        this.Columns = Int32.Parse("1");
        if (this.Rows == 0)
        {
            CreateANullTable();
        }
        else
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
             getJobAdsBasedonFilter();
        }

    }

  public void getJobAdsBasedonFilter()
  {

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    int ID = 0;

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP(10) s_JobDesignation,s_JobDescription,s_NoOfVacancies,s_DatePosted,s_JobId FROM [OfinityJobSearch].[dbo].[tx_ListOfJobs] WHERE s_IndustryName='" + industryName + "' ORDER BY s_JobId ASC ";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


        if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cmd.Connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())    
        {              
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {                    
                while (reader.Read())
                {    
                    JobDesignation = reader.GetString(0);
                    JobDescription = reader.GetString(1);
                    NoOfVacancies = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(2));
                    DatePosted = Convert.ToString(reader.GetDateTime(3)).Replace("00:00:00", "");
                    jobId = reader.GetString(4);
                    int tblRows = 1;
                    int tblCols = 1;

                    Table tbl = new Table();
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
                    for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
                    {
                        readerrowcount = readerrowcount + 1;
                        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                        tr.CssClass = "rowStyle1";
                        for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
                        {
                            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                            tc.CssClass = "cellStyle1";
                           System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label txtBox = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
                           txtBox.Text = "Job ID:" + jobId + "<br />" + "Job Designation:" + JobDesignation + "<br />" + "Job Description:" + JobDescription + "<br />" + "Vacancies:" + NoOfVacancies + "<br />" + "Ad Posted On:" + DatePosted + "<br />"+"";
                           tc.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                           tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                           System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lbView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();
                           lbView.Text = "<br />" + "Apply for this Job";
                           lbView.Click += new EventHandler(lbView_Click);
                           lbView.OnClientClick = "return RedirectTo('" + id + "');";
                           lbView.ID = "linkButton" + readerrowcount;       
                           tc.Controls.Add(lbView);
                           tr.Cells.Add(tc);                         
                        }

                        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

                    }
                    ViewState["dynamictable"] = true; 
                  } reader.NextResult();

            }

        } 

    }
    catch (SqlException exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "warning!", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    finally
    {

        if(cmd.Connection.State==ConnectionState.Open)
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
} 

    protected void lbView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The problem is when the job seeker clicks on FIND JOBS BUTTON, the jobs are listed **but the APPLY FOR THIS JOB is not firing at all.**

[image]

Please help.

Comment: You are calling javascript function. Do you get any error messages in console? Can you add breakpoint in the browser (using Firebug or Chrome) and see whether this method is called. Can you add html which is being generated for the job offer (particularly source of the apply button)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
   LinkButton lnkButton = new LinkButton();
   lnkButton.ID = "lnkdynamicbutton"; 
   lnkButton.Text = "Apply for this job";
   lnkButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnkButton_Click);

protected void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", "<script>alert('You Clicked me!!!')</script>");
}
```

Comment: In the lnkButton_Click() I want to navigate the job seeker to a page, where he can see the applied post and his uploaded resume and mail id to which he can be contacted.

Comment: I also wanted to know the id of the link button that is clicked, so that I can get the Job post which is applied.

Comment: in your question u have mentioned, link button event is not firing.so for that i have given answer.Now wat is ur requirement

Comment: its working fine in my application. then u might have missed something.

Comment: I have ONCLIENTCLICK event also. Even if i comment that the code is not working. Actually i am creating the dynamic controls in the FIND JOBS Button.

Comment: can u elaborte your requirement. So that i can help u.

Comment: Sure.When the user clicks on the link button, I want to navigate to a page where in he will be able to see the job that he has applied along with his other details.

Comment: The onclientclick event is working. Can you please suggest how I can get to know which Job has been applied i.e which linkbutton he has clicked so that i can track the job applied.

Comment: 1.get the id of that user from db and save it in a hidden field in the same row.
2.on linkbutton click pass that id as a query string.Example:Response.Redirect(/Details.aspx?id="hiddenfieldvalue").

Comment: I am able to retrieve the ID of the user. I want to retrieve the ID of the job that is applied.

Comment: instead of getting the id of user,get id of the job and save it in hidden field.then do redirect.or else u can go with repeater or datagrid